# Porque oracle no me devuelve todos los registros cuando hago un select desde c#

Tags: c#, oracle-11g

Estoy haciendo un insert y luego un select con oracleclient en c#. La consulta directa a la base de datos me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando hago el select desde una app windows forms me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta no la esta haciendo de sql porque las tablas tienen diferente nombre y en el caso de sql trae los datos bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como ven no me trae las filas que tienen la fecha null en la bd , porque pasa esto?. El código es este:**

```
private async Task cargar(string c)
    {
        string sentencia = "";

        DataTable dt=new DataTable();

        switch (c)
        {
            case "SQL":
                sentencia = "select * from pushes";

                using (var con = new SqlConnection("Server=zzzz;Initial Catalog=zz;User Id=zzz;Password=zzzz;"))
                {
                    await con.OpenAsync();


                        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sentencia,con);

                        adapt.Fill(dt);


                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
                break;
            case "ORACLE":

                sentencia = "select * from departamentos";

                List<departamentos> depas = new List<departamentos>();

                List<object> objetos = new List<object>();

                using (var con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=zzzzz/test;User Id=zzzz;Password=zz;"))
                {
                    await con.OpenAsync();

                    OracleDataAdapter adapt = new OracleDataAdapter(sentencia,con);


                    adapt.Fill(dt);


                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

para hacer el insert utilizo este código:

```
case "ORACLE":

                 sentencia = "INSERT INTO departamentos (depto_id,nombre,localidad,fecha_creacion)" +
                " VALUES" +
                "(:depto,:nombre,:local,:fecha)";

                using (var con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=localhost:1521/test;User Id=system;Password=sa;"))
                {
                    await con.OpenAsync();

                    using (var comando = new OracleCommand(sentencia, con))
                    {

                        comando.Parameters.Add("depto", 2);
                        comando.Parameters.Add("nombre", "oracle");
                        comando.Parameters.Add("local", "oracle");

                        comando.Parameters.Add("fecha", DateTime.Now);

                        var reader = await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync();


                    }
                }

                await cargar(comboBox1.Text);
```

Comment: falta un commit en el sqldeveloper? los registros estan mas abajo?

Comment: Los que tienen la fecha null en sql developer no los carga el Command en widnows forms

Comment: estas seguro que la ejecucion ingresa por el CASE de ORACLE ? has puesto un breakpoint en el codigo para asegurarte que pasa por el codigo por el cual crees que esta pasando

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Correcto. Si se fija las tablas en el select tienen nombres diferentes.

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar.. hiciste el commit en el sql developer? probaste ordenar los datos en las dos para ver si no estan mas abajo? cerra la sesion del developer, volve a abrirla y fijate si los datos estan. Estas seguro que son las mismas tablas?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini  También lo hice con un reader en lugar de un adapter y no trae los registros que tienen la fecha null

Comment: @gbianchi  No se de que me habla la verdad.

Comment: y por eso no ves los datos.. cuando haces un insert a una tabla desde el developer, el commit de los datos (la confirmacion de los comandos) no es automatica.. o sea, que lo que vos ves, no es lo que tiene la base de datos.

Comment: proba a escribir commit; y ejecuta ese comando, y fijate si tus datos aparecen

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta. El sql si funciona  bien.

Comment: El problema no esta en el codigo c#, sino conoces que es un commit en Oracle esta claro que no confirmaste los cambios, ve al sql developer y termina la operacion del insert. Sino confirmas el commit de los insert no quedan reflejados en la tabla, aun estan en la transaccion pendientes

Comment: Bueno eso no lo sabía. El código que use para el insert es ese que acabo de poner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con Oracle desde una tool de administracion necesitas confirmar las operaciones porque sino estas quedan pendientes en una transaccion

[Use the SQL Worksheet in SQL Developer to Insert, Update and Delete Data](https://www.oracle.com/tools/technologies/howto-sql-worksheet-insert-update-datele.html)

puedes escribir la linea

```
Commit;
```

al final de las operaciones de insert, update o delete que realices

O puedes usar el boton

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que se visualiza en la imagen

Comment: Pues eso no lo sabía. Ahora si me salen todos los datos. Excelente. Resuelto